# Passing params into MailView or ActionMailer::Preview in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible when using the MailView gem or Rails 4.1 mail previews to pass parameters into the MailView? I would love to be able to use query string parameters in the preview URLs and access them in the MailView to dynamically choose which record to show in the preview.

Comment: Anyone get this working with MailView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same issue and as far as I understand from reading the Rails code it's not possible to access request params from mailer preview.

Crucial is [line 22](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.6/railties/lib/rails/mailers_controller.rb#L22) in `Rails::PreviewsController` (email is name of the mailer method)

```
@email = @preview.call(email)
```

Comment: I am also trying to access param value on preview email. Coudn't understand your answer. Can you please explain @Michal

Comment: @vinothini It is not possible to access params from email preview.

Comment: if my PR gets approved you will be able to do it https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20608

Answer (score 2):

Still a relevant question and still very few solutions to be found on the web (especially elegant ones). I hacked my way through this one today and came up with this solution and [blog post on extending ActionMailer](https://ruby.unicorn.tv/articles/access-url-request-parameters-from-actionmailer-preview).

```
# config/initializers/mailer_injection.rb

# This allows `request` to be accessed from ActionMailer Previews
# And @request to be accessed from rendered view templates
# Easy to inject any other variables like current_user here as well

module MailerInjection
  def inject(hash)
    hash.keys.each do |key|
      define_method key.to_sym do
        eval " @#{key} = hash[key] "
      end
    end
  end
end

class ActionMailer::Preview
  extend MailerInjection
end

class ActionMailer::Base
  extend MailerInjection
end

class ActionController::Base
  before_filter :inject_request

  def inject_request
    ActionMailer::Preview.inject({ request: request })
    ActionMailer::Base.inject({ request: request })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [Rails 5.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8e6c6d854cdedad4bc082cf45a01d411ea26fb68#diff-f6f2a76ba21e6545e7e9b16601a9a64a89e743221ba2098a50a317bf08abe7e7), mailer previews now have a `params` attr reader available to use inside your previews.

Injecting requests into your mailers is not ideal as it might lead to thread safety issues and also means your mailers won't work with ActiveJob & co